# Kinect touchable Surface

Tags: c#, kinect, sensors, xbox, xbox-one

I have a programming project using Kinect Xbox one sensor. The project is mainly about turning any surface into an interactive touchable screen. I have collected all the hardware including the projector. In addition, I have done my research and downloaded the related packets such as Visual Studio in order to start coding in C#.

So, my question here: 
Is there any any library that I could use which may facilitate me to determine the angles/depth of the surface?

Plus, I don't have a fully vision of the steps which need to be done for the next steps, so I would really appreciate it if there is anyone could draw me a small map for me for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have trouble with getting started with kinect go through this
[Quick start series](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart)

and you also might want to capture the depth of objects. For that try to use Kinect's depth image streams and the sdk itself does not provide much happy methods. You will have to do some image processing on that gray scaled depth stream. Then you can find the edges of a single object in different depths.

Comment: thanks Shamitha, I would like to ask you something. What kind of output does the Kinect provide so we can start coding on C#? Does it have some libraries provided from Kinect community that may help me in some aspects? and will Kinect involve a lot of image processing codes?

Comment: The sdk itself won't provide the image processing procedures to identify the object's and it's edges. I think you guys are going to do touchable a surface so that a projector can be worked like a touch screen..So what I'm suggesting is if you have flat surfaces mostly you will get a same gray color number for that surface. by that you can find the ending edges easily when the color code changing position.